# How can I copy a table cell value to multiple cells with javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dynamic html table with a contenteditable attribute. 
As the table has more than 300 rows, it would not be convenient for users to insert data one by one.
How can I make my table be editable similar to excel spreadsheet?

```
<table id="tabla_tarifas" class="table table-hover table-condensed table-bordered ">

  <thead id="thead_tarifas" class="thead_tabla_fija">
    <th class="th_tabla" style="width:120px" >Fecha</th>  
    <th class="th_tabla" style="width:30px"  title='Abrir/cerrar tarifas para una fecha'> </th>  
      <!-- relleno los tipos de hab del grid de tarifas -->
      <?php $tipo="SELECT id_tipo_hab,tipo_hab FROM hab_tipo WHERE visible='S' ORDER BY tipo_hab"; 
        $ejecutar_tipo= $conectar->query($tipo);
        $td=0;
      while ($registro_tipo= $ejecutar_tipo->fetch_assoc()){
            $nombre=$registro_tipo['tipo_hab'];
            $id_hab=$registro_tipo['id_tipo_hab'];
        echo "<th class='th_tabla'>$nombre</th>";
        $td++;
        }?> 
</thead>

<tbody class="tbody_tabla_fija">
  <?php for ($i=1; $i <366 ; $i++) { 
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td style='width:120px'><span id='t$i'></span></td>";
    echo "<td style='width:30px'><input type='checkbox' checked name='abierta' title='Al desmarcar se cierra la tarifa para una fecha'/></td>";
    for ($k=0; $k < $td; $k++) { 
     echo " <td contenteditable='true'></td>";
    }

   echo " </tr>";

 } ?>  

</tbody>
```

Comment: You will have to accept value from that cell, then loop over all rows and set it to them.

Comment: add your code @vuguma

Comment: But I want to select only a few cells not all the row

Comment: I solved it with slickgrid.Thanhs